# A workaround for partial specialization of function template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, partial-specialization

Consider the following metafunction for an integral pow (it is just an example) :

```
class Meta
{
    template<int N, typename T> static constexpr T ipow(T x)
    {
        return (N > 0) ? (x*ipow<N-1>(x)) 
                       : ((N < 0) ? (static_cast<T>(1)/ipow<N>(x)) 
                                  : (1))
    }
};
```

How to write the stop condition for such a function ?

Comment: @n.m. please post the solution how would you overload that ipow function template, I'm done banging my head :D

Comment: With a nasty hack, I guess you could do `return (N > 0) ? (x * ipow<(N - 1) * (N > 0)>(x)) : ((N < 0) ? (static_cast<T>(1)/ipow<-N * (N < 0)>(x)) : (1));`. That's really gross, so I don't recommend it.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: JohannesSchaub-litb beat me to it, see his answer.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb : Why does the original version causes infinite recursion and not your nasty hack (It works well, I tested it, but I don't understand exactly why) ?

Comment: @Vincent because my nasty hack uses `<0>` as argument in the false branches, instead of ever-decrementing numbers. If you are at 0, the original version instantiates for -1, -2, ... without ending. The current (C++11) language does not prevent this recursion even if the condition of the branch is a compile time constant (as in your case).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb : Ok, so in the original version, the compiler continue the recursions in the false branches even if it is useless. With your hack, you manually stop this useless recursion at 0, that's it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Anytime you ask yourself "how to simulate partial specialization for functions", you can think "overload, and let partial ordering decide what overload is more specialized".

```
template<int N>
using int_ = std::integral_constant<int, N>;

class Meta
{
    template<int N, typename T> static constexpr T ipow(T x)
    {
        return ipow<N, T>(x, int_<(N < 0) ? -1 : N>());
    }

    template<int N, typename T> static constexpr T ipow(T x, int_<-1>)
    {
        //                             (-N) ??
        return static_cast<T>(1) / ipow<-N>(x, int_<-N>());
    }

    template<int N, typename T> static constexpr T ipow(T x, int_<N>)
    {
        return x * ipow<N-1>(x, int_<N-1>());
    }

    template<int N, typename T> static constexpr T ipow(T x, int_<0>)
    {
        return 1;
    }
};
```

I think you wanted to pass `-N` instead of `N` at the comment-marked position.

Comment: Why not simply remove the explicit template argument to `ipow`?

Comment: @Xeo bah it becomes confusing then, because some of the overloads (the one for -1) still needs the "N" so it requires an explicit argument. I guess it is more helpful as it is.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, since you're basically using the `N` for both direction and counting.

Answer (score 5):

A simple version might go like this:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int N> struct pow_class
{
    static constexpr T power(T n) { return n * pow_class<T, N - 1>::power(n); }
};

template <typename T> struct pow_class<T, 0>
{
    static constexpr T power(T) { return 1; }
};

template <unsigned int N, typename T> constexpr T static_power(T n)
{
    return pow_class<T, N>::power(n);
}
```

Usage:

```
auto p = static_power<5>(2);  // 32
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `static` members in a class template and specialize the class template. You might want to create a forwarding function template for convenience, though.